# Replacing the values of a list whilst there is a while loop

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop

So say I have `['habcuxabc929abc', 'tabc', 'q', 'jabcuabc9']`.

What I basically want to do is split each element in this list between the `abc`'s and count the remaining parts. So the list specified above would look like: `[3, 1, 1, 3]`. What I have done does that but the main thing I want to achieve is if this value is less than 2 then it removes all `abc`'s and replaces them with `q`'s. (This works so far, although it is probably not pythonic). If the value is greater than 2 then I just want it to remove the last `'abc'` and replace it with `q`, leaving all the previous `abc`'s as they are but I don't know how to do this, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
while n < len(list123):
    dummylist = [len(r.split('abc')) for r in list123]

    if dummylist[n] <= 2:
        print 'true'
        list123 = [i.replace('abc',' q ') for i in list123]
        n=n+1
    elif dummylist[n] > 2:
        print 'false'
        list123 = [i.replace('abc',' q ') for i in list123]
        n=n+1
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is kind of hard to follow... Is there any way you could make the first couple of sentences a little more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, a `while` loop is the wrong choice here, and having the `split` *inside* it seems ludicrous.

Secondly, you don't want to `replace` all of the items in `list123` if any happen to have fewer than two parts; only modify `list123[i]` as you iterate over each index `i`.

Thirdly, to remove only the last `'abc'` you can use `str.rsplit` and specify a maximum of one splits, then `str.join` back together with `'q'` instead.

This is much neater:

```
dummylist = [len(r.split('abc')) for r in list123]
for i, n in enumerate(dummylist):
    if n <= 2:
        list123[i] = list123[i].replace('abc', 'q')
    else:
        list123[i] = 'q'.join(list123[i].rsplit('abc', 1))
```

This gives me `list123 == ['habcuxabc929q', 'tq', 'q', 'jabcuq9']`.

Comment: Thank you! This looks very nice will definitely come in handy!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it looks like you want something close to:

```
lst = ['habcuxabc929abc', 'tabc', 'q', 'jabcuabc9']
for i in range(len(lst)):
    dummy_lst = lst[i].split('abc')
    if len(dummy_lst) <= 2:
        lst[i] = ' q '.join(dummy_lst)
    else:
        lst[i] = 'abc'.join(dummy_lst[:-1]) + ' q ' + dummy_lst[-1]
print(lst)
```